# What is faster - using int *s = new int[size] or int s[size] + std::fill_n(s, size, 0);?

Tags: c++, performance, new-operator

Im just wondering ... read about malloc and static allocation. It is obvious that static way is faster. But how about this: instead of doing:

```
int *s = new int[100];
```

I would write:

```
int s[100];
```

and then use:

```
std::fill_n(s, 100, 0);
```

will it be faster too? I mean, I have 2 operations, than just one:

`int s[100];` and `std::fill_n(s, 100, 0);` instead of just `int *s = new int[100];`

Comment: Another option: `int s[100] = {0};`

Comment: Why not just create a benchmark and see for yourself?

Comment: You don't need to fill a static variable with 0's

Comment: @WeatherVane That is assuming that `s` is static, not a local. I suspect it's a local, though.

Comment: The language standard doesn't say which is faster, and it can vary from one implementation to another and with different compiler options. For something that small, any performance difference almost certainly doesn't matter. If it's big enough to matter (say, if you're doing it a billion times in a loop), you can measure it -- which will give you results that may be valid only for your particular configuration. Asking the question took many orders of magnitude more time than initializing an array of 100 `int`s.

Comment: You don't have two operations, unless by "operation" you mean something like a statement. You just have one operation. `int s[100];` isn't an operation, it most likely just gives a name to some space on the stack so you can perform operations on it later.

Answer (score 2):

These two expressions are not equivalent:

- The first one allocates an array from dynamic store (also known as "the heap"),
- The second one allocates an array in the automatic store (also known as "the stack").
- The first expression does not value-initialize the array
- The second expression fills the array with zeros explicitly

Generally speaking, stack operations are faster, because they are implemented in hardware: essentially, the allocation portion is free. The call of `new[]` and `delete[]`, on the other hand, are also heavily optimized, so you would see very little difference in most situations.

If you wish to initialize the `new` array with zeros, you need to put parentheses after the array size, like this:

```
int *s = new int[100]();
//                   ^^
```

Comment: so filling up with zeros is faster than using malloc? I have to add, I use malloc in a loop ... and when I use automatic variable, then I my loop I use std::fill_n instead of malloc

Comment: @mirx `malloc` does not fill with zeros; `calloc` does. If you want an array filled with zeros in both situations, then your second snippet (i.e. `int s[100]; std::fill_n(s, 100, 0);`) would be faster.